# What is the difference between QChar::isDigit() and QChar::isNumber()?

Tags: c++, qt

I read the documentation, it says for [QChar::isNumber()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qchar.html#isNumber) that

> Returns true if the character is a number ([Number_*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#number) categories, not just 0-9);

However, when I click on the [Number_*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#number), it sends me to a http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#number, which is about Style Sheets, and it doesn't make sense - what do Style Sheets have to do with QChar?

So to know the difference, I need to know what those Number_* categories really are, and I think the link in the documentation doesn't explain it, instead it points me to documentation about Style Sheets.

Comment: in QChar::isDigit() there is fixed [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qchar.html#Category-enum) which should point to what you are looking for

Comment: So the link in the docs really was broken?

Comment: Looks like it was autogenerated with wrong link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (correct) hint is hidden in the documentation `isDigit()`:

> Returns true if the character is a decimal digit ([Number_DecimalDigit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qchar.html#Category-enum)); otherwise returns false.

Here, the `Number_*` link is correct:

> ```
> QChar::Number_DecimalDigit    3   Unicode class name Nd
> QChar::Number_Letter          4   Unicode class name Nl
> QChar::Number_Other           5   Unicode class name No
> ```

So `isNumber()` will check if the given `QChar` is part of the unicode classes [`Nd`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), [`Nl`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm) or [`No`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm). For example, [㊱](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/32b1/index.htm) is classified as "Number, other", whereas [Ⅱ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/32b1/index.htm) (roman numeral two) is classified as "Number, letter".

Comment: Can you give some examples for those class numbers, or links that give more info about them? The other answer mentioned '½' as one example.

Comment: @sashoalm: Sure: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm

Answer (score 3):

"½" is a character. It is a number, but it is not a digit.